# Why can't I instantiate a CFC's method using New

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-2018

I am trying to instantiate a CFC using this simple syntax

```
<cfset Sale = New pathtocfcfolder.sale.GetSale(SaleID = URL.id) />
```

When I run the above I get an error saying

> Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface
>   pathtocfcfolder.sale.GetSale

However if I just instantiate the component without the method it works fine like this:

```
<cfset Sale = New pathtocfcfolder.sale() />
<cfdump var="#Sale.GetSale(SaleID = URL.id)#" />
```

The GetSale function is basically this:

```
<cffunction name="GetSale" returntype="Query" access="public">
  <cfargument name="SaleID" type="numeric" required="true" />
  <cfstoredproc procedure="dbo.GetSale">
   <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" dbvarname="@SaleID" value="#ARGUMENTS.SaleID#"/>
   <cfprocresult name="rsSale" resultset="1"/>
  </cfstoredproc>
  <cfreturn rsSale /> <!--- returns the query from the database --->
 </cffunction>
```

Comment: Does new pathtocfcfolder.sale().GetSale() work?

Comment: @Redtopia Yes it just worked. I'll be damned for not trying that earlier! On a side note, I am using about 4 methods from the `Sale.cfc` component, so would it in fact be better to instantiate the whole component like in my code and then get data from that new instance like this `<cfset Sale = New pathtocfcfolder.sale() /> <cfset SaleItem = Sale.GetSale()/> <cfset SalePayments = Sale.GetPayment()` etc

Comment: Yes, you are creating an instance of the component either way, so there's no reason to not have a variable for it and then invoke methods on it.

Comment: The primary point of instantiating a component is so that you can use multiple methods (or the same method multiple times) without having to recreate that component each time. That's a big difference between `New`/`CreateObject` and `cfinvoke`.

Comment: Also on an OT note: `cfscript` > `cftag`. Just sayin. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at what I think the intent is, your folder structure is probably something like:

```
\pathtocfcfolder
.. Sale.cfc
page.cfm
```

The error actually tells what the issue is: there is no `GetSale`component.

With `New pathtocfcfolder.sale.GetSale(....)`, you're trying to instantiate the `GetSale` component in the folder `pathtocfcfolder\sale\`. CF doesn't know that `sale` is supposed to be a component. That's why Redtopia's suggestion worked. By using `sale()`, you've told ColdFusion that the folder to look in is `pathtocfcfolder` and start with the `sale` component because of `()` functions/methods. Then CF immediately calls `GetSale(...)`.

This isn't really what `New` is supposed to do. It's meant to instantiate components (or objects) and not functions/methods of those components. It *can* (or at least appear to do so), but that doesn't mean it should. Especially if you are going to use other functions inside of your object. Instantiate the component once and reuse it.

If you only wanted to use a function from inside a component once and then throw the component away, you can use `cfinvoke` to call that function. Otherwise, you'd want to instantiate the object and call the functions on that object as you need them.

On a side note, since you are using ColdFusion 2018, you can use `new component("pathtocfcfolder.Sale")` (instead of `new pathtocfcfolder.Sale()`) to instantiate the component and then use `Sale.GetSale(...)` to call your function. The 2018 syntax makes your intent a little clearer.

I'll also add back in my caution about using `URL` variables directly in code. Sending them to a Stored Procedure will handle much of the SQL Injection issues, but I'm of the opinion that the first thing a user-supplied variable should do is go through at least some basic sanitation and validation. People can be very not nice to your aplication.

Comment: If you only wanted to use one method from a component, would instantiating just the function/method use less resources or does it make no difference?

Comment: You are still instantiating the object wither way.

Comment: Functions aren't really intended to be "instantiated". The objects/cfcs that contain those functions are. If you only want to use an object's functions once, then use `cfinvoke`. Regardless, you have to create the object to use its functions. `cfinvoke` will create the object, use the function you request, then destroy the object and free its resources. It can be process-intensive to create an object, so you don't want to do it more often than needed. Thus `New`,`createObject`, etc and then calling the object's function from that. It really depends on your needs.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I understand OO, but I don't understand how ColdFusion works underneath the hood in terms of what is CPU and memory intensive. OT: Are there any resources for understanding how to make best use of CF from a performance point of view such as instantiating objects as few times as possible?

Comment: I understand the concern of your question, but I suspect there isn't resource. Not every `.cfc` is equal. Some are created because they are a part of ORM, some are tied to sessions, so it does not matter how slow they are. To your original question, I suspect that invoke would be fastest, but it certainly can be tested. Maybe that is the short answer, test it and see how it goes.